# Safari border-radius clipping on a table

Tags: css

I have a situation where a parent element has a border-radius with a solid color border. This works as expected in all browsers except for Safari (5.1.7). In Safari, the child element's background color is bleeding into the border, and background-clip doesn't seem to be helping. Iv'e seen other people have similar issues that were resolved, is this an issue specifically with tables? Any ideas as to why the clipping doesn't apply properly?

http://jsfiddle.net/q3NF9/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following CSS:

```
thead th:first-child {
   border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}
thead th:last-child {
   border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

See example:
http://jsfiddle.net/q3NF9/8/